# Classic ASP - Display all dates within a certain date range

Tags: date, asp-classic

I was wondering if i could get some help.

I have a little script that gets a date range based on a persons input.

It outputs the date range like so

```
6/7/2014

6/27/2014
```

What i need to do is output each date between these 2 dates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates in Classic ASP are fairly easy to use.  Try this first: http://www.classicasp.aspfaq.com/date-time-routines-manipulation/could-i-get-a-little-help-with-dates.html

Here's a demo of looping through a series of sequential dates:

```vb
dim dcount, newdate
dcount = 0
newdate = startdate
do
    response.write(newdate & "<br />")
    newdate = newdate + 1
loop until newdate > stopdate
```

Obviously you'd need to specify `startdate` and `stopdate`, though this could be done as a `sub` or `function`.

Comment: Be careful if using different date formats as you could come unstuck. Prime example is `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy`.